# XmlElement.GetAttribute not working

Tags: xml, vb.net, xml-parsing

I have an XML with this structure:

```
    <table>
      <header>
        <c0 type="string">name</c0>
        <c1 type="ip_address">last_ip_address</c1>
      </header>
      <body>
        <r>
          <c0>CHDB207</c0>
          <c1>172.18.151.57</c1>
       </r>
      </body>
   </table>
```

What I want to receive is the type value for each c-header element

> string ip_address

I have the following code:

```vb
Dim header As XmlElement = document.DocumentElement
Dim headerList As XmlNodeList = document.SelectNodes("table/header/*")
MsgBox(header.GetAttribute("type"))
```

However, I only get a blank value... Looking at the attribute in debug mode I do not get any information displayed?

Anyone any idea? Using VB.NET

Comment: Does `document.SelectNodes("table/header/*")` return any nodes?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `header` element is declared but never assigned to the `c0` and/or `c1` elements.

```vb
Dim headerList As XmlNodeList = document.SelectNodes("table/header/*")

For Each header As XmlNode In headerList
    MsgBox(header.Attributes("type").Value)
Next
```

Comment: This did the trick! Thank you very much - working now. I knew it was just a small thing missing but I ain't no pro-coder ;)